# how to rename create folder with hexadecimal number based on time date

Tags: date, echo, mkdir, mv

Want to create or rename my image or data folders according to time, date and with a name in hexadecimal format

date +%y%m%d
echo -n "`date '+%y%m%d'`/{1,2,3} "
mkdir `obase=16; 'date '+%y%m%d'`' | bc
mkdir -p `echo -n 'date '+%y%m%d'`/{1,2,3} ' | od -A n -t x1

noting work :(

Answer (score 0):

x=`date +%y%m%d%H%M | bc` && y=`echo "obase=16; $x" | bc` && mkdir $y

dir

83CB3212

Also can use mv to rename the folder
Note "If the folder already exist when you use mv it moves the folder into it"